# Templated list of templated objects in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create a list of objects, where each object also stores 'ownership' - ie, it knows which list holds it.

In a non-template situation, it's straightforward:

```
class FooList;  // forward declaration

class FooItem
{
  public:
     FooList *owner;
  ...
};

class FooList: private std::list<FooItem>
{
  ...
};
```

However, the list class is a template, based on the contained object type, and I'm struggling to work out how to specify this. I reckon the FooItem class now needs to be a template because the type of 'owner' can vary:

```
template <class E> class FooItem
{
  public:
     std::list<E> *owner;
};

template <class E> class FooList: private std::list<E>
{
  ...
};
```

But, now given my two templates, how can I define the new types I want? The snippet below is what I think I need, but it gives `"error: Multiple declaration for BarItem"`.

```
class BarItem;

typedef FooList<BarItem> BarList;
typedef FooItem<BarList> BarItem;
```

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks to those who pointed out the issue of `std::list<E>` instead of `std::list<FooItem<E> >`

---

**EDIT 2:**
Renamed classes to `Base, Derived, BaseList, DerivedList.`

My real problem was the 'circular typedef'. After some more tinkering, I think this will do what I require. It creates a 'real' BarItem class rather than just a typedef, but seems to at least compile now.

```
template <class E> class BaseList; // forward declaration

template <class E> class Base
{
  public:
     BaseList< Base<E> > *owner;
};

template <class E> class BaseList: private std::list< E >
{
};

// typedef Base<BaseList<Derived> > Derived;  //This won't compile, unsurprisingly.

class Derived : public Base < BaseList<Derived> >  // Surprisingly, this seems to.
{
...
};

typedef BaseList<Derived> DerivedList;
```

Does this seem to make sense? Is it a common idiom or something horrible?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you didn't want:

```
template <class E> class FooItem
{
  public:
     std::list< FooItem<E> > *owner; // owned by a list of FooItem<E>, not raw E
};

template <class E> class FooList: private std::list< FooItem<E> > // is a list of FooItem<E>, not raw E
{
  ...
};
```

The error you are getting is because you forward declare the class `BarItem` but later try to redefine that name using `typedef`.  Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you'll need to introduce a third name.  Maybe you meant:

```
class Bar;
typedef FooItem<Bar> BarItem;
typedef FooList<Bar> BarList;
```

---

EDIT: The new code you've posted certainly compiles, but seems very awkward (for one thing, the naming seems really confusing).  Perhaps you should ask a new question with a more concrete example of why you think you need an 'item which is an item of lists of itself' and see if others can come up with a less awkward design.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've updated the question showing what I think is an 'answer' to my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Is that last set of `typedef` statements correct?  You posted this:

```
class BarItem;

typedef FooList<BarItem> BarList;
typedef FooItem<BarList> BarItem;
```

It's somewhat recursive, right?  The first statement says there's a class `BarItem` that exists elsewhere.  The second statement says that the type `FooList<BarItem>` (a list of `BarItem` objects) can also be referred to as `BarList`.  The third statement says that the type `FooItem<BarList>` can also be referred to as `BarItem`, but `BarItem` was already defined as a type by the `class BarItem` statement.

So you're saying that `BarItem` is a type all to itself (via the `class` statement), but you're also saying that `BarItem` is an alias for the type `FooItem<BarList>`.  Hence the conflict.

Comment: `So you're saying that BarItem is a type all to itself?` :No - I'm trying to somehow 'forward declare' BarItem, but I'm struggling with the syntax.

Comment: The point I was attempting to make was that by forward declaring `BarItem` (which you can do by something like `template <class E> class BarItem;` if the class is templated) and then also trying to use it on the right hand side of a `typedef` expression, you're going to get a conflict.  If there's a class that exists somewhere called `BarItem`, then you can't also do `typedef SOME_TYPENAME_HERE BarItem`.

Comment: I guess I was trying to forward-typedef a typedef... doh. Does my updated question (with possible solution) make more sense now?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to generalize your first approach to a templated `FooItem` class, it would look like this:

```
template <class E> class FooList; // forward declaration

template <class E> class FooItem
{
  public:
     FooList<E> *owner;
  ...
};

template <class E> class FooList: private std::list< FooItem<E> >
{
  ...
};
```

If that is not what you want I'm not sure what exactly you are attempting to do.